# Does the python vm compiles method every time?

Tags: python, vm-implementation

If I have a function that is called in few places in my module, does the virtual machine compiles it to native code only the first time the function is executed and than use the cashed code on the other calls? (like .NET jit compiler)

Comment: Python does not compile functions to machine code. There's no viable transparent JIT for it yet. (Though look at [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/), it can do wonders sometimes.)

Comment: @9000: IronPython, Jython, PyPy?

Comment: @denlan: IronPython and Jython use underlying JITs of JVM and CLR. AFAIK, Jython with JVM's JIT runs about as fast as plain CPython. Is PyPy ready for production?

Comment: @9000: Yes they use VMs not specifically build for Python - so what? And word is they're still usually faster than CPython. PyPy 1.4 "only" implements Python 2.5 (supposedly, the next version should come soon and be compatible with 2.7) but was declared ready for production use.

Comment: @9000 Talking about the standard Python implementation - something has to transfer the Python code to machine code during runtime who does it?

Comment: @Ohad: No, nothing has to translate the bytecode to machine code. The bytecode is interpreted by a C program (which makes happen what the bytecode describes, to perhaps it could count for some weird definition of "tranfer to machine code").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In CPython (the standard Python implementation) the first time a Python module is imported, it's compiled to bytecode and stored in a .pyc file.  From then on, the .pyc file is read and interpreted by the VM when needed.  Once the .pyc is read into memory, the bytecode is in memory, and interpreted by the VM when the function is called.

CPython never compiles Python code to native executable code.

Comment: And the implementations that do JIT-compile (IronPython/.NET, Jython/JVM, PyPy) are not stupid enough to throw the result away.

Comment: @ned-batchelder So pyc file is created every time I run even a simple script?

Comment: @Ohad: No. As he says, the `.pyc` file is created the first time the file is run (or rather, the first time it's run after the latest change) and reused afterwards.

Comment: The .pyc file is a cache of the the compiled bytecode.  It is only recreated when needed.  As @delnan says: the .pyc is re-made if the .py changes.